# How to create a table which is a subset of another table in CALC

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In (Libreoffice) CALC I have a table with a number of rows. How can I create a second table based on the first where only specific rows are present, dependent on one of the cell values in each row? This is obviously pretty easy to do manually by selecting the rows and sorting them etc., but is there a way to do it manually so I don't have to re-sort each time I get a new list and without having blank rows?

Example

| Name | Employee |
| --- | --- |
| John | 100 |
| Fred | 101 |
| Bill |  |
| Steve | 104 |
| Janet | 105 |
| Mary |  |
| John | 106 |
| Homer |  |

I want to remove all the rows without an employee number so end up with

| Name | Employee |
| --- | --- |
| John | 100 |
| Fred | 101 |
| Steve | 104 |
| Janet | 105 |
| John | 106 |

with no blank rows (other than at the end)

Thanks

I did consider MATCH, INDEX etc., however everything I can think of ends up with blank rows. I also want to avoid manual sorting each time.

Comment: Welcome! You need a **filter** instead of a **sort**. Please see [**Data - More Filters - Standard Filter**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/02/12090100.html?DbPAR=CALC) and pay attention to the [**Options**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/12040201.html?&DbPAR=CALC) button - there you can specify the place where the table you need will be located without empty values in the Employee column (**Copy results to**)